# Single database connection throughout the whole app?

Tags: database, performance

A web app that was programmed in a interpreted language (like PHP), and that uses a database (like MySQL), will instantiate a database object and make a new connection each time it handles a request.

A web app that was programmed in a language that compiles a binary (like Go), will generally make a database connecton that will be running through the whole process and will be used in all HTTP requests that the app will handle.

If that's a fact, is it safe to assume that performance wise, the compiled program will be always the best choice?

Answer (score 4):

> If that's a fact,

It is not.

> is it safe to assume that performance wise, the compiled program will be always the best choice?

No, that's not really a feature of whether a language is compiled or not, but related to the database API you use or create yourself irregardless of the language.

### Single application wide connection

An app utilizing a single database connection will fail to exploit parallelism available at the database server, and will be sensitive to the network latency between the app and the database server, as all requests are serialized over the same connection. A naive use of this approach also sets up a database connection at startup, and have to be restarted if that connection breaks.

### Connection per HTTP Request

At the other end, setting up 1 connection per http request can be inefficient as the intial handshake with the database takes time, and the database can be overwhelmed by too many parallel connections.

### Connection Pooling

What you normally want is a [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) that maintains up to a max number of connections available for handing out to any thread, and re-used when a thread is finished using the connection. The [database/sql](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB) package in Go does such connection pooling, given that the driver properly implements it, other database APIs might not - and you could always implement a connection pool yourself. PHP has  [different](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) [variants](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.pooling.php) of connection pooling too, sometimes called "persistent connections" (Though implementing such a connection pool yourself would prove difficult given the process model that PHP uses)

Answer (score 1):

There are two extreme approaches here:

1. a quick connection, opened each time a DB access is needed;
2. a long connection, established once and keep open forever.

The first approach has a cost in terms of performance, because establishing a connection to the DB is not negligible.

The second one has some drawbacks, because the connection can timeout, or can be dropped. So it should be controlled and re-established when needed.

If the number of connections is not very high I'd suggest the first approach, it's simpler and reliable.

If you plan to have many connections and you think that the cost of establishing each time a new connection can be an issue, then I suggest to use some library to manage a [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).